# Windows Phone 8 - Launch an app from within an app

Tags: calendar, windows-phone-8

is it possible to launch an app from within an application?

In my case it would be launching default calendar application.

Thank you,

Jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to launch an app from another app, using file and URI associations:

[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

However, there is not any URI scheme to launch the calendar app in the list of the available URI schemes for built-in apps:

[URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

So, unless there exists any hidden URI scheme for that purpose, I think the only available workaround is to use the `SaveAppointmentTask`:

[How to use the save appointment task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to search for the hidden association.

Comment: In Windows Phone 8.1 you can start the default calendar app with `Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowTimeFrameAsync(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));`